# ARRAYFORMULA FILTER VLOOKUP solution for multiple condition formula Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need an ARRAYFORMULA, VLOOKUP or FILTER formula in K7 that:

Puts the date from A7:A IF the value in J7:J is >= E7:E AND <= F7:F AND D7:D = "Traverse"

I have got multiple solutions to work on the individual rows, but none to work as an array formula to effect the entire column.

```
=IF(AND(J7>=E7:E,J7<=F7:F,D7:D="Traverse"),OFFSET(J7,0,-9),"")
```

or

```
=IFERROR(FILTER(A:A,E:E<=J7,F:F>=J7,D:D="Traverse"))
```

or

```
=ArrayFormula(IFNA(vlookup(J7:J2064,Query(sort(filter({date("20"&left(A7:A,2),mid(A7:A,3,2),right(A7:A,2)),A7:G},D7:D="Traverse"),6,1,1,0),"Select Col6,Col2",0),2,1)))
```

an example sheet is here if anyone can shed any light  :)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SYbhfyIA2KoZF0k-TuIqm-Kn9L9o0I16EGbSXDaTABU/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, in the end I managed to get a formula working from someone on the Google help forum. This is a working solution if you're interested:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFNA(vlookup(J7:J,sort({filter({Register!E7:F,Register!A7:A},Register!D7:D="Traverse")
;if({index(sort(filter({Register!A7:A,Register!E7:E,Register!F7:F},Register!D7:D="Traverse"),2,1),0,2);""}
>{"";index(sort(filter({Register!A7:A,Register!E7:E,Register!F7:F},Register!D7:D="Traverse"),2,1),0,3)},
{{"";index(sort(filter({Register!A7:A,Register!E7:E,Register!F7:F},Register!D7:D="Traverse"),2,1),0,3)}+1,
{index(sort(filter({Register!A7:A,Register!E7:E,Register!F7:F},Register!D7:D="Traverse"),2,1),0,2);""},
iferror({index(sort(filter({Register!A7:A,Register!E7:E,Register!F7:F},Register!D7:D="Traverse"),2,1),0,2)
;""}/0,"")},)},1,1),3,1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((J7:J>=E7:E)*(J7:J<=F7:F)*(D7:D="Traverse"), A7:A, ))
```

[image]

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(J7:J, SORT({
 FILTER({E7:E,  A7:A}, D7:D="Traverse"); 
 FILTER({F7:F+1,H7:H}, D7:D="Traverse")}), 2, 1)))
```

Comment: Thanks Player,  it populates every cell from 184600 onwards with only 2 dates. when only about 10% of the values fall within the criteria and there should be several dates, Im a bit baffled... Could it be something to do with the values in column J?

Comment: @JonBowles fixed the vlookup fx.

Comment: Still seems to do the same thing?

Comment: @JonBowles see formula in P7. the output is all rows with traverse. what vlookup does is it takes number in J column and if that number is equal or higher than number in P column than it will summon value(date) from Q column

Comment: Thankyou Player0,

But can you see there are about 90% of the values in column J that do not fall within the range of column E & F, but yet still have a value/date in column K. For example anything from 186800-312300 (1255 rows) that have a value/date in column K but shouldn't as there are no corresponding values in column E & F for those values...

Comment: @JonBowles I see, try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(J7:J, SORT({FILTER({E7:E,A7:A}, D7:D="Traverse"); FILTER({F7:F+1,H7:H}, D7:D="Traverse")}), 2, 1)))`

Comment: Thats better, but now there are gaps. For example 184510-186700 should have 210622, but only some of them do...  Can I also ask what is the purpose of the H7:H in your formula?